# what is the meaning of qmake config

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In my .pro file , I have found this snippet:

```
 win32 {
        CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {

            LIBS += $$(QwtDir)/lib/qwtd.lib\
                    version.lib

            } else {

            LIBS += $$(QwtDir)/lib/qwt.lib\
                    version.lib
        }
```

I looked at the documentation of qmake and it said you can use `CONFIG` as a conditional statement, and they gave an example of `CONFIG(debug)` , which means if in debugging mode, but what about `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)`? what does it mean?

Comment: It's well described in the official docs http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#config

Comment: @Puciek, thank you. My question is very simple: Is it ok to replace CONFIG(debug, debug|release) with CONFIG(debug, release)?

Comment: I don't know, can you? Does it work when you do? Does it satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I don't know either, that is why I am asking... :)

Comment: You are missing the point. The first one - does it work you can quickly test. As for the latter, whether this is the droid you are looking for - that only you know.

Comment: it depends what you mean by "it works". I was able to build it but it seems to me that in debugging mode it is still asking for libraries from release mode...so I am not sure if the problem is coming from .pro settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When qmake processes a pro file it could process it up to three times depending on what the configuration is set to. Usually it will do it three times. Once for debug, once for release and one final one for debug_and_release*
>
> *...this construct CONFIG(debug, debug|release) ... checks for when the debug configuration is being processed comparing where “debug” and “release” are mutually exclusive.*

This is taken from the detailed explanation [here](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/what_does_the_syntax_configdebugdebugrelease_mean_what_does_the_1st_argumen).